# Iterating through a matrix of irregular row lengths

Tags: javascript, matrix, iteration

I've got a matrix where rows don't necessarily have the same length:

The following are musical tokens in the format of solfege.

```js
const notes = [
    [ 'do5', 'mi5' ],
    [ 'mi6', 'so6', 'ti6', 're7' ],
    [ 'so7', 'ti7', 're8', 'fa8' ],
    [ 'la3', 'do4', 'mi4' ],
    [ 'fa2', 'la2' ],
    [ 're2' ],
    [ 'ti1', 're2', 'fa2' ]
];
```

I have a function that converts these tokens into equivalent alphabetic tokens (for example: fa2 would be converted to F2 using my function).

I would like to be able to iterate over this matrix, and return the transformed matrix, which should retain the same dimensions.

Thanks,
Nakul

Comment: you can use 2 `map()`s if you have a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: `Array.forEach()` 2 times

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript that you already tried? We have no idea what you may or may not already know.

Comment: You just changed your question stating that you need to return a "matrix of the same size". What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I apologize @LucioPaiva, I just modified my question to better explain what I mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you probably want:

```js
const notes = [
    [ 'do5', 'mi5' ],
    [ 'mi6', 'so6', 'ti6', 're7' ],
    [ 'so7', 'ti7', 're8', 'fa8' ],
    [ 'la3', 'do4', 'mi4' ],
    [ 'fa2', 'la2' ],
    [ 're2' ],
    [ 'ti1', 're2', 'fa2' ]
];

// replace this function with your own converter
function convert(note) {
    return note.toUpperCase();
}

for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {  // for each row
    // map will iterate through the row, converting each note
    notes[i] = notes[i].map(convert);
}
```

The part `map(convert)` is just a shorter form of `map(note => convert(note))`.

This is not very efficient, as `map()` will create a new array for each row, but in your case it's probably more important that the code is readable rather than performant, so that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new `Array.prototype.flat()` function, but, if you want wider support (`.flat()` is ignored by both Edge and IE), then I would use two `for..of` loops.

```js
const arr = [
  [ 'do5', 'mi5' ],
  [ 'mi6', 'so6', 'ti6', 're7' ],
  [ 'so7', 'ti7', 're8', 'fa8' ],
  [ 'la3', 'do4', 'mi4' ],
  [ 'fa2', 'la2' ],
  [ 're2' ],
  [ 'ti1', 're2', 'fa2' ]
];

// Modern JavaScript
for (const item of arr.flat()) {
  console.log(item);
}

console.log('----');

// More widely supported JavaScript
for (const subarray of arr) {
  for (const subitem of subarray) {
      console.log(subitem);
  }
}
```